# SQL: Query used in online guide for ttfb doesn't return any results in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, chrome-ux-report

To create automatic sitespeed reports I have been following this guide: [How to create a site speed report based on crux](https://www.brainlabsdigital.com/blog/how-to-create-a-site-speed-report-on-data-studio-based-on-chrome-user-experience/)

However when I paste (and change the crux database to a specific country and month) the following code. It doesn't return any results.
Of course, I did change the website in the code.

```
 select
yyyymm,
sum(case when ttfb.start < 201 then ttfb.density else 0 end) as fast,
sum(case when ttfb.start > 200 and ttfb.start < 1001 then ttfb.density else 0 end) as average,
sum(case when ttfb.start > 1000 then ttfb.density else 0 end) as slow
from(
select 
*, _TABLE_SUFFIX AS yyyymm
FROM
`chrome-ux-report.country_ca.202012*`
where not regexp_contains(_TABLE_SUFFIX, ".*20(20|21).*") and origin='https://mywebsite.com/'),
UNNEST(experimental.time_to_first_byte.histogram.bin) AS ttfb
group by yyyymm 
order by yyyymm asc
```

I have also tried running

```
FROM
`chrome-ux-report.all*`
```

Also return no results.

Any ideas as to why this might be?
Help is appreciated!

EDIT:
When I put the same code into Google Spreadsheets, it says there are no parameters. Could that have anything to do with it?

Comment: The query doesn't look syntactically correct to me.  But your question does not suggest a syntax error.

Comment: It doesn't say there's any syntax errors. I can run the code, but I just don't get enough results. I'm not exactly experienced enough to see where there's an issue with the code. Thank you for your reply